# Google Street view error on local test

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I try to test "Custom Street view panoramas " and get this error. Below is image captured on `apache` local server

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved :):

change this:
`<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initPano"></script>`

for this:

`<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initPano" type="text/javascript"></script>`